# Liquid error "No such template" in Rails

Tags: partial, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

I'm getting the following error in my Liquid view:

```
Liquid error: No such template 'sliders/slider' #<Liquid::LocalFileSystem:0x99319b8>
```

The file structure in my liquid code (which saves in the database) has the following code:

```
{% include 'sliders/slider' %}
```

and in my view where I render the Liquid content is as follows

```
<%
Liquid::Template.file_system = Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new("sliders/slider")
@template = Liquid::Template.parse(<page code>) %>
<%= raw @template.render(<variables>)  %>

<%= Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new("sliders/slider") %>
```

And in app/views/sliders/ I have a file called '`_slider.erb`'.

But if I do a `<%= render :partial => "sliders/slider" %>` it shows the file

Am I missing something here? I'm using Rails 3 with Liquid 2.2.2 and on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your partial filename should be: _slider.**liquid** for it to work properly.